# How to use file apis with sveltekit netlify

Tags: svelte, netlify, sveltekit

I have code like this

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import type { SvelteComponent } from 'svelte';

const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir);

export async function getAllPosts() {
    const files = (await readdir(`src/data/posts`)).map((i) => i.replace(/.svx$/, ''));
    return files;
}
```

and my server route

```js
import { getAllPosts } from '../../lib/blog';

export async function get() {
    return { body: await getAllPosts() };
}
```

and it works fine in development, but it doesn't work in production on netlify, because there isn't really a `src/data/posts` directory anymore. How can I get sveltekit to generate this array at buildtime?

I have tried using the static adaptor but it doesn't generate the routes properly becuase although there are links to all the pages on the site, they aren't generated right away. So I think I have to go with the netlify adapter.

Comment: I figured out a way to get it to work with `adapter-static` however I'm leaving this open as I figure it will be usefull for others.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the `/src/data/posts` folder does not exists anymore and thus your code does not work.

The first thing you have to do is to *copy* your assets to the `/functions` folder so that they are available in the first place.

Then you have to make sure your script looks in the correct place, here there is some magic going on with the function not being executed in the same location as it is placed. You can read more on this on the Netlify support forums, in a topic like [this one](https://answers.netlify.com/t/hosting-a-file-along-with-my-function/1527/19).

If you finally find a working solution maybe add it here as an answer as well.

Comment: Will do although I won't need to do this until I need something not statically-generatable on my site. Thanks for your reply. I think It might be able to be handled at the svelte level like monkey patching the file apis to make them work exactly as they do for any other generator. What do you think?